# Why shell returned a Python error traceback when I `cd` into python-skeleton dir

Tags: python, zsh, cd

I installed Pycharm via HomeBrew cask on my OS X 10.10. I heard python-skeleton is something useful so `cd`ed into it to find what does it have. But every time I type `cd /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pycharm/4.5/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/python-skeletons/` gets this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 527, in main
    known_paths = removeduppaths()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 110, in removeduppaths
    dir, dircase = makepath(dir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 80, in makepath
    dir = os.path.join(*paths)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Anything else is alright, it only appears when I cd into the special dir.

I'm using zsh and oh-my-zsh. After bi-searching as @skyline75489 mentioned, I find out it's something wrong with the autojump config in my .zshrc file:

```
[[ -s $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ]] && . $(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```

Comment: Why on the earth will a python program raised an error when you are not even running one?

Comment: @skyline75489 Yeah, that's what i'm most curious about. I thought maybe there is a hook by zsh or something else?

Comment: That's possible. You can use bash to try it, or replace your current .zshrc with an empty one.

Comment: @skyline75489 You're right, I think it's something wrong with autojump, which will index any path after `cd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, it's exactly what the exception says: `os` module has no attribute `path`. `python-skeletons` has [a package called `os`](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/tree/master/os), and the `os` package in the current working directory when you are in `blahblah/python-skeletons` is shielding the `os` package from standard library. This is because present working directory comes before library paths in `sys.path`, the list of paths where Python look for modules.

In general it's rather bad practice to have a module or package that has the same name as an STL module or package (unless it is designed to be a drop-in replacement), but in this case it's there, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Just don't `j` from or to that directory. If your `cd` is shielded by a function or alias for `autojump`, then use `builtin cd` instead.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, any good idea to fix this problem? Like a PR for autojump that move the python dir in the front of present dir, so autojump will use builtin os instead?

Comment: @kxxoling I'd say no; as I noted above, this is `python-skeletons`'s fault. Anyway, submit a ticket if you feel like it; I'm not a Python expert so maybe there are tricks I don't know.

Comment: Um... I found the fault comes when site.py is called before every python program is running. Not only autojump, but any python program cannot start, and it's really hard to hack this and maybe also needless. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm weird, now that I looked at `python-skeletons` more closely, it actually *has* [`os.path`](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/blob/master/os/path.py), and it *is* a drop-in replacement. If I clone the repo, then I would have no problem running any Python program using `os` in the project root. Can you confirm there are valid `os/__init__.py` and `os/path.py` in your `.../python-skeletons`? Maybe the installed version is somewhat different? After all I don't have it installed and can't because there's no `setup.py`. I also don't have PyCharm.

Comment: I moved the module to an empty dir, but cannot start ipython either, but python runs OK. `import os; os.path.join` gets the same error, but `from os import path; path.join` runs OK.

Comment: Uh yes, that's the issue. The `os.path` module isn't imported in the `os` package's [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/blob/master/os/__init__.py) (Python does not automatically import subpackages or modules  when you import a package). That's why. Probably something `python-skeletons` should fix.